# Website logo displaces list on navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm learning how to markup with html and css and have been experimenting, and have a little problem that has left me scratching my head.

I'm using text as a placeholder logo rather than a img, but for some reason it displaces the list from the navbar and pushes it below. However, when I remove the logo the list moves back into the navbar.

*But!* I've tried using inline-block, float, and more following what already asked questions I can find yet nothing seems to solve my issue.

Here is the code with the logo: (made in Notepad++ if it makes any difference)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <body>
            <nav class="nav">
                <div class="logo">
                Website
                </div>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </body>
</html>
```

And this is it without the logo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <body>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit: I apologize, attempting to format this in the code tags is proving difficult. It merges my css and html into one tag.

```
body, html {
    margin : 0px;
}

nav {
    width : 100%;
    background-color : #0099cc;
    height : 40px;
    font-size : 22px;
    font-family : Verdana;
    line-height : 40px; 
}

ul {
    list-style-type : none;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0
}

nav , logo , ul {
    display : inline-block;
}

li{
    float : left;
    border-right : 1px solid black;
}

li a {
    display : block;
    padding : 0px 15px;

    color : white;

    text-align : center;
    text-decoration : none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color : #007acc;
    color : white;
}
```

Comment: thats the normal behavior of `floated`, `inline`, or `inline-block` elements. try putting `white-space: nowrap;` on the `container`. it will prevent the child elements from wrapping down.

Comment: look at your css where you define logo instead of `.logo {  }`.

Comment: @Lara Belle, thank you. That seemed to work. It is displaying properly now although I'll need to adjust the padding but I have a question, how does using . differ from ,  and #? The book I am learning from does not make any note of how the three work differently.

Comment: @KyleSosnicki check my answer. Maybe, it can help you. Welcome :)

Comment: It did help @Lara Belle, although I admit I jumped right in to notepad when I saw your comment and saw your answer after I put it in.